# Error al crear carpeta con php en EC2

Tags: php, linux, aws, ec2

Tengo una instancia EC2 en Amazon, en la cual corro un servidor apache. El problema se presenta al querer crear una carpeta con php, el codigo que estoy utilizando es este:

```
mkdir("test", 0777, true);
```

Pero me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/prueba/prueba.php on line 2
```

Alguien sabe como se puede solucionar esto?. Gracias

Comment: ¿ Usuario con el que ejecutas PHP, permisos y usuario dueño de la carpeta **padre** en la que quieres crear otra ?

Comment: php esta corriendo en el servidor, yo entro desde la web a ejecutar el archivo. Lo otro que me preguntas como puedo averiguarlo?. Yo cree todo. Gracias!

Comment: Desde ssh y ftp lo puedo hacer sin problemas. Gracias

Comment: A traves de ftp puedo ver que dice permisos: -rw-rw-r-- y Propietario/Grupo: ec2-user ec2-user

Comment: primero verifica a quien le pertenece las carpetas y ejecutas `sudo chown -r www-data:www-data` luego `<?php !is_readable($folder) ? chmod($folder, 0777): ""; ?>`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he logrado solucionarlo cambiando los permisos de la carpeta a 775 y agregando el usuario ec2-user como propietario. Gracias!

Comment: @Patricio yo tengo el mismo problema en el permiso me aparece Drwxrwxr-x como puedo agregar usuario ec2